# When trying to create a struct in release mode, sometimes i get the error like "Variable is optimized away and not available"

Tags: c

Sometimes my program crashes with errors like "`Variable is optimized away and not available`" or "`Unable to read registered value`". But sometimes the program runs fine until I try to use the remove  function, and than I get the *error that the "temp" variable is optimized away and not available*, when trying to remove the last node.

I don't know what any of those errors mean.

I need to make a linked list that every node contains a struct and the next node. A struct inside the node is a frame, which means it contains the image showing duration, `(unsigned int)`, **image** name `(char*)` ***image directory*** `(char*)`.

If the directory is not found, the user will be asked to enter a correct directory, and in my opinion that's when the errors mostly come from. (I say "in my opinion" because i cannot use break points in VS because i get the error "The break point will not currently be hit. No executable code for the debugger's target code type is associated with this line."(I run the program in release because "**openCV**" doesn't work for me in debug).

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "printMenu.h"
#include "linkedList.h"
#include "view.h"

FrameNode* createFrame()
{
    unsigned int frameDuration = 0;
    char* frameName = 0;
    char* imagePath = 0;
    int imageFound = 0;
    FILE* checkImage = 0;
    Frame* newFrame= 0;
    FrameNode* newNode = 0;

    newFrame = (Frame*)malloc(sizeof(Frame));
    newNode = (FrameNode*)malloc(sizeof(FrameNode));

    frameName = (char*)malloc(256);
    imagePath = (char*)malloc(256);

    printf("Choose duration of image: ");
    scanf("%d", &frameDuration);
    getchar();
    printf("Name the image (Must be a uniqe name): ");
    fgets(frameName, 256, stdin);
    frameName = (char*)realloc(frameName, strlen(frameName));
    frameName[strcspn(frameName, "\n")] = 0;

    while (!imageFound)
    {
        printf("Enter image path: ");
        fgets(imagePath, 256, stdin);
        imagePath = (char*)realloc(imagePath, strlen(imagePath));
        imagePath[strcspn(imagePath, "\n")] = 0;
        printf("%s %d %s", frameName, frameDuration, imagePath);

        if (checkImage = fopen(imagePath, "r"))
        {
            imageFound = 1;
            fclose(checkImage);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("No such directory!\n");
        }
    }

    imageFound = 0;

    newFrame->duration = frameDuration;
    strcpy(newFrame->name, frameName);
    strcpy(newFrame->path, imagePath);

    newNode->frame = newFrame;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

void addFrame(FrameNode** head)
{
    FrameNode* curr = *head;
    FrameNode* newNode = 0;

    newNode = (FrameNode*)malloc(sizeof(FrameNode));
    newNode = createFrame();

    if (!*head)
    {
        (*head) = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        while (curr->next)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = newNode;
    }

}

void listFrames(FrameNode* head)
{
    FrameNode* curr = head;

    if (!curr)
    {
        printf("No frames found.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Name          Duration          Path\n");
        while (curr)
        {
            printf("%s          %d          %s\n", curr->frame->name, curr->frame->duration, curr->frame->path);
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}

void removeFrame(FrameNode** head, int length, char* imageName)
{

    FrameNode* curr = *head;
    FrameNode* temp = NULL;
    int found = 0;

    temp = (FrameNode*)malloc(sizeof(FrameNode));

    if (length == 0)
    {
        printf("No frames found!\n");
    }
    else if (length == 1 && !strcmp((*head)->frame->name, imageName))
    {
        *head = NULL;
        printf("Frame removed.\n");
    }
    else if (!strcmp(curr->frame->name, imageName))
    {
        *head = (*head)->next;
    }
    else
    {
        while (curr->next || curr || found)
        {
            if (!strcmp(curr->next->frame->name, imageName) && !found)
            {
                temp = curr->next->next;
                free(curr->next);
                curr->next = temp;
                printf("Frame removed.\n");
                found = 1;
            }
            curr = curr->next;
            printf("Loop.\n");
        }
        if (!found)
        {
            printf("Frame not found!\n");
        }
    }
}

void playGif(FrameNode* head)
{
    play(head);
}






//************************************
// Method:    freeList
// Returns:   void
// Description: Frees list.
// Parameter: intNode * list
//************************************
void freeList(FrameNode* list)
{
    FrameNode* temp = NULL;
    FrameNode* curr = list;
    while (curr)
    {
        temp = curr;
        curr = (curr)->next;
        free(temp);
    }
        list = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `frameName = (char*)realloc(frameName, strlen(frameName));` is wrong, it is not including space for the terminator. It's also very much pointless, and you would be about 100 times better off by just using a statically sized array for this.

Comment: @unwind Sadly we are forced to use dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Are you running this in a debugger ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker No, openCV doesn't work for me in debugger mode because of an error "msvcp120.dll not found".

Comment: *my program crashes with errors like ...* not really. AFAIK the error message you get is something which gets printed in e.g. the Watch Window or the Immediate Window in VS and it's not directly related to output of the program nor the reason of the crash. So you should figure out the actual error message, or specify how exactly you get this one, or at least the exit code.

Comment: Then what gives you the error if not the debugger ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Yes i am running in debugger sorry.

Comment: Debugging a release build is often not helpful as you found out. Are you looking to figure out why you can't get a debug build ? Or are you looking to figure out how to debug a release build ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I want to figure out how to debug a release build with break points.

Comment: @xing It is a pointer, and that might be the problem i will try and let you know.

Comment: @xing That was the problem, thank you.